# How to find the index of the second minimum in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame, the first 5 rows look like:

```
              High        Low          Open     Close    Volume Adj Close
Date                        
2003-12-01  1.204007    1.194401    1.203398    1.196501    0.0 1.196501
2003-12-02  1.210903    1.194600    1.196101    1.208897    0.0 1.208897
2003-12-03  1.213003    1.207700    1.209000    1.212298    0.0 1.212298
2003-12-04  1.214403    1.204398    1.212004    1.208094    0.0 1.208094
2003-12-05  1.219096    1.206593    1.207802    1.218695    0.0 1.218695
```

After ploting the 'Low', there are two ridiculous extreme values.
[image]

I know how to find the lowest one by using `data[['Low']].idxmin()`, but how to locate the second minimum without delete the first minimum?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the two values with lowest values using `nsmallest`

```
df['Low'].nsmallest(2)
```

To get the index of the second lowest value:

```
df['Low'].nsmallest(2).index[1]
```

Note, that this approach assumes there are no duplicate values.

If there are duplicates, then we need to get the index out as a list. This approach, while longwinded, will achieve that.

```
df.reset_index().sort_values(by='A').groupby('A')['index'].apply(list).reset_index().iloc[1]['index']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `sort_values` with `head`

```
df.low.sort_values().head(2).index[1]
```